# how to intecept custom http in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-http

i create a custom http extends HttpInterceptor, like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router:Router,
              private store: Store<fromAuth.State>){

  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>,
            next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req).do(evt => {
      console.log(evt);
      if(evt instanceof HttpRequest){
        console.log(evt);
      }
      if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
        if(evt.status === 401){
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        }else if(evt.status === 202){
          console.log(evt);
          this.store.dispatch(new auth.LoginSuccessAction(evt.body));
        }else if(evt.status === 200){
          console.log(evt);
        }
        else{
          console.log('other')
        }
      }
    });

  }
}
```

and then add this in my appModule providers :

```
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
```

now it worked,my http can be intercepted with httpClient!

then i created a custom http by extends Http:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthHttp extends Http {


....
```

also add in appModule providers:

```
{AuthHttp},
```

this AuthHttp is still worked!
But i found that my `AuthInterceptor` could not intercept `AuthHttp`
how to fixed this ? thank!

Comment: Are you mixing old Http with new HttpClient?

Comment: it can be intercepted by httpClint, but when i use custom authHttp , it not work

Comment: First, HttpInterceptor only exists since Angular 4.3.something. Not in Angular 2. And it intercepts requests made with the new HttpClient. Not those made with the old, soon-deprecated Http service. Stop using the old Http service. Use HttpClient.

Comment: thank verymuch  :)